# I'm trying to put an if statement after return and I want to know how to change this

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'dart:ui';

import`enter code here` 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
  State<HomeScreen> createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
XFile? video;
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(body: if(video=null){randerEmpty();}return (video!=null)        
{renDervideo();};)
// video == null ? randerEmpty() : renDervideo())**
;
} 

Widget renDervideo() {
return Center(
  child: Text('video'),
 );
 }

Widget randerEmpty() {
return Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  decoration: getBoxDecoration(),
  child: Center(
    child: (Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        _Logo(onTap: onLogotap),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30.0,
        ),
        _textbox()
      ],
    )),
  ),
);
}
```

If I put the commented part below it works fine. But when I try to change it to an if statement, an error occurs. I think it's a problem in return, but I can't figure out the answer, so I'm asking for help.

Answer (score 1):

You got it, you can't use the instruction `return` when assigning a named parameter (`body` in this case).

The commented part is the cleanest solution, is there any reason you can't just switch to it?

UPDATE:

In case you need a *if, else if, else* structure, you can achieve that with something like:

```
condition1 ? result1 : (contidion2 ? result2 : elseResult)
```

Comment: I was reviewing to prepare for a situation where if ,else if,else was needed later. Usually in flutter, there are many cases where i can't put an if statement in the body because of the return, butis this the best way.

Comment: Oh, i get it. You can also use nested inline ifs to simulate an if, if else, else. I'll update my answer to show that.